# Display dialog code not executing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a button that on click should display a dialog, but seems that the code is not executing.

Here is the onclick code:

```
profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("--", "dasd");
                displayPopup();
            }
        });
```

and displayPopup function

```
private void displayPopup() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select option:");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        arrayAdapter.add("Call " + employee.getName());
        arrayAdapter.add("Send SMS to " + employee.getName());
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }
```

The Log.v is executing but displayPopup() is not. Can anyone tell me why is this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and show your dialog. Add this to the end of your `displayPopup` method:

`builderSingle.create().show();`

Edit: As Alex said, `builderSingle.show()` does the same thing. If you call `create()` you then have a handle to a dialog which you can call `show` on at a later time. From the docs for [`Builder.create()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29):

> Creates a AlertDialog with the arguments supplied to this builder. It does not show() the dialog. This allows the user to do any extra processing before displaying the dialog. Use show() if you don't have any other processing to do and want this to be created and displayed.

Comment: create() is not necessary

Comment: Indeed, I just learned this after reading your answer. This way was in the first dialog code I saw, and it's just become muscle memory to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now it creates and empty dialog. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: You never specify content - specifically, you create an adapter without calling `singleBuilder.setAdapter`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `builderSingle.show()`